# Can't style HTML5 elements in IE (despite shiv and display:block)

Tags: css, html, styles, semantic-markup

I can't seem to work out what's missing. All the affected elements have `display:block`

Example style for the `header` element:

```
header
{
    width: 923px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #395168;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: What IE version, and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: IE 6-8. The main issue is that the background color is not showing.

Comment: Do you load shiv on <head>? Could you show us a demo page? Does the header get correctly width, height and margin-top?

Comment: Here's the page: stenius-online.com

Comment: Hard to say exactly what it could be, but saving the page (in IE8, full page - not .mht) fixes the header background, but breaks the body (and the site is not centered anymore). Maybe you could look into that. An try the usual suspect: zoom:1 on the header.

Comment: It works fine for me in both IE7 and 8, so I suspect you've fixed it?

Comment: Weird. Have not made any changes. Just tried it in IE 8 through Parallels Desktop, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. What i did was that i put the script-link under the stylesheet link and suddenly IE 6-8 applied my styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thank you so much for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

IE 6-8 doesn't know about the **header** tag, so that the styles can't be applied to it. To make IE to understand this tag, add the below script in your **head** section.

```
<script language='javascript'>
document.createElement('header');
</script>
```

This would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try giving it a class?

Comment: He's selected it correctly via CSS so it should apply the style theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't currently allow styling to be applied to these elements.  The way I solve it is by wrapping them in another div:

```
<div class="header">
    <header>
    </header>
</div>
```

This isn't great obviously, but it beats any solution that relies on JS as it won't display strangely with JS disabled.

Comment: Hum.. Did the IE-testing in Adobe Browser Labs. Does it even support JS? If not that's probably the answer. Have to get hold of a PC so i can test it for real. Will get back with an answer as soon as i do.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem myself today, upgraded to latest html5shiv code (now moved to Github here: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), moved the stylesheet above the script link, all elements had display:block set but still no luck styling them...

The I realised I had no doctype declaration in my markup - adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

solved the problem, all styles now applying correctly - so complete solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- html 5 markup -->
    </body>
</html>
```