# HTML5 SHIV and display: block -but styles still break in IE<9- Why?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

If my site works fines in IE9, and I've included the HTML5 SHIV code, but the CSS still breaks in IE8,7, are there some obvious things I should troubleshoot first?

Here is my site, works fine in IE9, breaks(the top nav loses formatting, positoning)in IE 8-7.
http://bitstream.ca/beta3/#

I've also included

```
header,nav,article,footer,section,aside,figure,figcaption{display:block}
```

in my page CSS

And ALSO included the shiv script AFTER my CSS but still within my head tag as per this suggestion
[Can't style HTML5 elements in IE (despite shiv and display:block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368971/cant-style-html5-elements-in-ie-despite-shiv-and-displayblock)

These types of CSS -IE bugs are pretty difficult to troubleshoot for anyone who hasn't come across them before,

Comment: The top nav looks the same in IE7-9. The page is quite slow to load though, which means you might see the fonts flash over to the web font. Are you sure you haven't changed the **Document Mode** to **Quirks**?

Comment: Ok thanks. The problem may be that I am using IE9 with document mode set to IE7,8. I thought using IE9's document mode for testing would be accurate enough?

Comment: It is fairly accurate. But you need to make sure you change the Document Mode as well as the Browser Mode i.e. if you are testing IE7 then it needs to be Browser Mode: IE7  & Document Mode: IE7 Standards. I'll put it in a solution.

Comment: Ok, the issue is that when using IE9 for testing, you MUST set both document AND browser mode at the same time. This seems like a major flaw in IE. Strange to me that you need to set the browser mode as well, since its the document mode that determines rendering...

Comment: The Document Mode and the Browser Mode will change simultaneously, if IE isn't in Quirks Mode (double check if a lowercase "doctype" is understood by IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Developer Tools in IE you need to make sure you change both the **Document Mode** as well as the **Browser Mode** e.g.

Settings for testing IE7 -
Browser Mode: IE7
Document Mode: IE7 Standards

Settings for testing IE8 -
Browser Mode: IE8
Document Mode: IE8 Standards.

etc.